# Popular shows feature artists designing ...

Tags: participle-clauses, gerund-clauses

> Popular television shows feature artists designing everything from new clothes to delicious food dishes.

Why don't use "who design" in the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construction, a *gerund clause*<sup>†</sup>, has quite a different sense than a relative clause.

In the sentence “Popular television shows highlight artists **who design** everything ...”, the object of the verb *highlight* is *artists*:

> [<sub>subject</sub>Shows] [<sub>verb</sub>highlight] [<sub>object</sub>artists] ...

What you are shown is people—artists—and the relative clause adds information about what kind of people you see.

In the sentence “Popular television shows highlight artists **designing** everything ... ”, the object of the verb is the **entire clause** which follows:

> [<sub>subject</sub>Shows] [<sub>verb</sub>highlight] [<sub>object</sub>artists design everything from ...]

What you are shown is not people, but ***actions***—people-doing-stuff.

The verb *design* is cast into the *-ing* form so the clause may act like a noun and serve as a direct object; but otherwise it is an ordinary sentence. Grammarians call this a *subordinate* or *embedded* clause, because it is “lower than” or “stuck inside”  something bigger.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>*Gerund* is the traditional name for an English *-ing* form which acts as a noun. When it acts as an adjective, or as a component of a progressive construction, it is called a *participle*. The important thing to keep in mind is that in both cases it **also** acts as a *verb*. That is the origin of the name *participle*: it is something which “participates” in the qualities of two different word classes.</sub>